# Is this a brass or copper elbow pipe under the sink?

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink

I just noticed that an elbow pipe under the sink had corroded through with a leak at the first elbow and needs replacing.  I temporarily fixed it with some flex tape and I need to find out what replacement pipe I need to order from Amazon.  Should I replace with a brass pipe or will PVC do fine as well?

Questions

1. What kind of pipe is that - copper?  Brass?  What do you call those tightening sleeve rings on it so that I know what to order?
2. What caused the corrosion at the elbow- are the big U pipes at the bottom brass?  If it's a mixture of copper and brass, it because it mixes copper with brass?
3. I noticed some white spotting on the longer elbow that the first elbow is connected to - should that be replaced as well?  Will it corrode too?  It seems 5” tall is that a standard size or would I have to get it cut?  I’m at home with no access to outside stores.
4. Is 12cm circumference == to 1 1/2 inch pipe?

[image]

Comment: I would probably replace the brass with plastic, easier to cut to length. And way cheaper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Brass.

You will probable not find that elbow at an all-round home improvement center, you will need to go to a dedicated plumbing supply house. ( *take the elbow with you to insure you get a match* ).

The "tightening sleeve rings" are called [slip joint nuts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00GE9Y06G), it  is likely that yours are still fine and reusable.

Because  the top of your  elbow is connected to the drain basket it is acting like a tail piece. A tail piece to basket connection is not a slip joint, it uses a flat washer instead of a slip joint washer but it does use the same nut. For this reason it may be difficult to find the correct elbow.

If you do decide to replace it all with plastic you will need to know what the interface is with the Sanitary tee in the wall. It appears to be a threaded connection and a plastic set up would have a slip joint connection, even if it is threaded you should still be able to slip the 1 1/2 plastic pipe into it but investigate it before buying parts.

Also you will want a  [dishwasher branch tail piece](https://www.homedepot.com/p/KEENEY-1-1-2-in-x-8-in-Plastic-Dishwasher-Branch-Tailpiece-PP931-8PVC/304826866) . It appears you do not have an air gap for your dishwasher but it is best to have one, it may be code in your area, if not put in a high loop.( [explained in this stack question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/41349/what-is-causing-my-kitchen-drain-to-back-up-into-my-dishwasher) )

Answer (score 0):

Looks like brass , not as red as copper. One of the few household materials that will corrode it is ammonia which is in some cleaners. Ammonia is also corrosive to copper. Ammonia will also cause stress corrosion cracks in brass.

Comment: If it's brass would I just look for a 1.5" brass elbow pipe? What would I call those tightening sleeve rings when I do a search for it?  Do the tightening rings come with the pipe or do I remove and reuse the same one from one pipe to the replacement.